# Can I start nix-shell with packages from different revisions?

Tags: nix, nix-shell

I can start `nix-shell` with a package from a particular revision, e.g.

```
nix-shell -p ktlint -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/141439f6f11537ee349a58aaf97a5a5fc072365c.tar.gz
nix-shell -p jq -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/7d7622909a38a46415dd146ec046fdc0f3309f44.tar.gz
```

Can I start `nix-shell` with two packages, but from different revisions, in one command? For example, if I wanted both `ktlint` and `jq` from the specific revisions above?

Comment: FWIW -- personally, I would have asked this one at [unix.se]. Questions about Nix-the-language are definitely best suited to SO, but questions about the associated command-line tooling is iffier.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the helpful answer, and you're undoubtedly right - I've been learning about Nix as a potential development environment tool, but this question is not super specific to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=...` is just syntactic sugar enabling references like `<nixpkgs>` to work; but one doesn't need to use `import <nixpkgs>` exclusively -- one can also import directly from an explicit path.

```bash
nix-shell -E '
let
  pkgsA = (import (builtins.fetchTarball https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/141439f6f11537ee349a58aaf97a5a5fc072365c.tar.gz) {});
  pkgsB = (import (builtins.fetchTarball https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/7d7622909a38a46415dd146ec046fdc0f3309f44.tar.gz) {});
in
pkgsA.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
    pkgsA.ktlint
    pkgsB.jq
  ];
}'
```